# nose using the same Python instance?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

How can I force `nosetests` to run each unit test in a new Python instance?

I'm having a weird situation here, I have a simple plugin system based on enumerating `__subclasses__()` of a `Plugin` base class out of which plugins are derived. My problem arises from the fact that `nosetests` seems to reuse (?) the python instance to run all unit tests and, because of that, one of the unit tests ends up "seeing" a plugin defined in another.

For a proof of concept, I have the following directory structure:

```
.
|-- package
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- plugin.py
|-- unit_test_1.py
`-- unit_test_2.py
```

The contents of the files can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/3hPBy812). Now, if I run `unit_test_1.py` or `unit_test_2.py` individually, they both succeed. However, if I use `nosetests` to run both of them, the second unit test will failed due to the length of `__subclasses__()` being two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `nosetests --with-isolation`:

> Enable plugin IsolationPlugin:  Activate the isolation plugin to
>   isolate changes to external modules to a single test module or
>   package. The isolation plugin resets the contents of sys.modules after
>   each test module or package runs to its state before the test. PLEASE
>   NOTE that this plugin should not be used with the coverage plugin, or
>   in any other case where module reloading may produce undesirable
>   side-effects.

Your example will pass both tests.

Comment: Uh. I tried --with-isolation before asking the question and I got tons of exceptions; and yeah, I'm using coverage too :( Any other way of doing this? (I'm gonna look tomorrow into --with-isolation some more, maybe I can make it work)

Comment: it's going to be hard to get coverage and using multiple instances at the same time - you would have to deal with a merge of multiple runs.